Trying to use file's hash as password in Inno Setup
I'm trying to make it so you can only proceed with the installation in Inno Setup, if you provide a file whose contents' hash has an expected value. The file is about 40 kilobytes.
Here's the code I have commented out for now
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
var Page: TInputFileWizardPage;
begin
  Page := CreateInputFilePage(wpWelcome,
    'Select SMB1 ROM file', 'A legally obtained SMB1 rom is required to proceed & get access to this port',
    'Click "Browse..." and select your SMB1 ROM file, then click Next.');

  Page.Add('&SMB1 ROM file:',
    '.NES|*.nes|.NEZ|*.nez|.UNF|*.unf|.UNIF|*.unif',
    '.nes');
end;

And I found this for MD5 hashes but I just don't know what to do here and how to properly do what I want with it
https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getmd5ofstring
And this for passwords
https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CheckPassword
Kindly, can someone with more experience please help me?

After sifting through the documentation, this is what I came up with:
[Code]
var Page: TInputFileWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  Page := CreateInputFilePage(wpWelcome,
    'Select SMB1 ROM file', 'A legally obtained SMB1 rom is required to proceed & get access to this port',
    'Click "Browse..." and select your SMB1 ROM file, then click Next.');

  Page.Add('&SMB1 ROM file:',
    '.NES|*.nes|.NEZ|*.nez|.UNF|*.unf|.UNIF|*.unif',
    '.nes');
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if CurPageID = Page.ID then begin
    // if GetSHA256OfFile(Page.Values[0]) = '<put in the SHA256 hash here if you''re going to use this>' then
    if GetMD5OfFile(Page.Values[0]) = '<put in the MD5 hash here if you''re going to use this>' then
      Result := True
    else begin
      MsgBox('Please select an actual SMB1 rom.', mbError, MB_OK);
      Result := False
    end;
  end else
    Result := True;
end;

I had to make the variables you used global so that the entered values can be access for your use case.
I'll explain what it does if you don't know:

We initialize the variables we want to use first, since if we initialized them in a function/procedure, they would stay local to it and we won't be able to access them anywhere else.

We then create the page that would ask you for the correct file in the InitializeWizard procedure. We don't do the validation there.

Then we would validate the file when the user clicks "Next" in the NextButtonClick function. It takes in a number for the current page's ID, and every page has its own ID (including the one you made), and we use that to check whether we are on the page for the file prompting thing or another page we don't care about validating.
In the case when the current page happens to be the one we made, we get the file path from Page.Values[0] and pass it to the GetMD5OfFile function which takes in the file's path and returns the file's hash (in MD5 of course). I put it directly inside the if statement to save a line, but you could also use a seperate Hash variable if you would want to.
In that if statement, we check if the returned value matches the hash we want (for legal reasons I won't provide you with the hashes here).
And if it is, we return True to tell Inno Setup to proceed, otherwise display an error message and return False to tell Inno Setup NOT to proceed (and stay on the page).


The solution uses MD5 as its hashing thing since that's probably what you wanted, but MD5 is considered insecure now and shouldn't be used anymore.
You should use SHA256 instead by using GetSHA256OfFile and checking its result against the SHA256 hash of the file you want to verify. The code for it is commented out, just remove the two slashes and the line after it.
